# How to retrieve and display the value of radio button from database in C#

Tags: sql, radio-button, dataset

I have two radio buttons: Yes and No.

I store values of the selection (0 or 1) into the SQL database. Now I would like to display the values of those radio button from database to the user when loading the form using dataset.
Here is my code:

```
    public void LoadRequestInfo()
    {
        CommonCollection c = new CommonCollection();
        var CTS = c.COMPTRACKERCONNECTIONSTRING();
        var CTS_conn = new SqlConnection(CTS.ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CTS_GetRequest", CTS_conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", "100221"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestId", "CD558017-8CEA-496D-9537-A53E1E2BA8AD"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            CTS_conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            CTS_conn.Close();

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               txtTitle.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][17].ToString();
               drpProperty.SelectedItem.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
               drpCategory.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
               rdYes.Checked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString(); //Here is the part I have problem.
               rdNo.Checked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][14].ToString();
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display the result of radio buttons:

```
Boolean IsYes = Boolean.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString());
if (IsYes == true)
{
    rdYes.Checked = true;
    txtPenalty.Visible = true;
}

else if (IsYes == false)
{
    rdNo.Checked = true;
    txtPenalty.Visible = false;
}
```